# How to send a XMPP message from Android to GAE using Smack

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, xmpp, smack

I want to send XMPP message from my android client to GAE Server using Smack.
I read [this post](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/) with gmail settings and got the idea of how it should be done. But I don't how to setup the `host` and `serviceName` for my google app engine account.

```
String host = "talk.google.com";
int port = 5222;
String serviceName gmail.com;

ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host ,port , serviceName);

XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
connection.connect();

Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
msg.setBody(text);
connection.sendPacket(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP can work over a few different transport mechanisms.

GAE works on HTTP, so your XMPP client will probably have to support BOSH (XMPP over HTTP)
Here's the spec: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html

You would then use the URLs and XMPP addresses described in the GAE XMPP docs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview

I haven't seen any documentation specifying a port # for GAE XMPP, I suspect it's not supported, so you won't be able to connect over sockets.

Comment: Thanks, It is a bit more clear to me now. I didn't see any java code in the link. Perhaps you know a tutorial in java?

Comment: Perhaps you can use google to search for 'xmpp bosh java client'.

Comment: Hi @dragonx. I've been trying to create an XMPPConnection but the the connection fails. The XMPPServer starts OK, though. Could you please look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245311/xmppconnection-doesnt-connect) and see if you can help? thank you in advance.